# SharePoint 2016 with SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I fully understand that SharePoint 2016 DBs must be on SQL SERVER 2016+. My question is *NOT* related to SharePoint databases (DBs SharePoint uses to manage the site).

However, my environment has many 2008R2 databases. SSRS reports run independently through Report Server (2008 Report Server). **However**, we also have SharePoint2010 (through Excel services) grabbing data from both SQL Server 2008R2 DBs as well as SSAS (2008). What is the compatibility of those with SQL Server 2008R2?

Could Excel Services (Office Online) access SQL 2008? Are there any documentation on these compatibilities? Because I was unable to find anything.

Comment: There is [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-external-data-in-excel-services-sharepoint-server-a00e5a66-017e-4956-bd40-49639ad1f1d0) and also [this](https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2012/07/using-the-new-excel-2013-data-model-with-sharepoint/). hope it helps.

Comment: @JohnKelheim thank you, this gave me a very good point to look for. However, those links 1) were for 2013, and 2) did not specify, even for 2013, what versions of SQL would be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with SQL 2008/R2, but this article gives no limitation to the used AS-Versions:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219634(v=office.16).aspx#Software%20requirements%20for%20Excel%20Online

> If you plan to use Excel Online with advanced data models, at least
>   one SQL Server Analysis Services in SharePoint mode must be registered
>   in the Office Online Server configuration. Excel Online can use
>   multiple Analysis Services servers, but they must all use SQL Server
>   Management Studio. For more information, see Download SQL Server
>   Management Studio (SSMS). Note that if you use multiple Analysis
>   Services servers with Excel Online **they don't need to be SQL Server**
>   **2016**.